# How can I hide the screen header but show my back button?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I would like to hide my screen header but still show the back button in my Stack Navigator? I have set screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }} in my Stack.Navigator, which hides both the screen header and back button. I would like to just hide the screen header.

Can someone please assist with this? Below is my Stack Navigator:

```
function SearchStack() {
   return (
     <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="SearchScreen" component={SearchScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="SearchListScreen" component={SearchListScreen} />

     </Stack.Navigator>
   );
}
```

In the tab navigator the stack is set as:

```
   <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {...})}> 
    <Tab.Screen name="Search" component={SearchStack} />
   </Tab.Navigator>
```

This is what I'm currently seeing:

[image]

But this is what I would like to have with my Tab navigation bar still at the bottom for the search stack:

[image]

This is what I get using options={{headerMode:"none"}} in Stack.Navigator:

[image]

The below occurs when adding updating the Stack.Navigator to <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerTitle:"", headerTransparent:true }}> . How can add or move the back button to the top exactly like the 2nd image, which is achieved when not adding the Stack to the Tab.Screen so changing:

<Tab.Screen name="Search" component={SearchStack} />

to

<Tab.Screen name="Search" component={SearchScreen} />

but doing this causes the tab to not appear in the Search list screen.

[image]

Comment: you have to add this line in tab.navigator also **screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}**

Comment: Thanks. Actually, in my Tab.Navigator I have something in screenOptions as shown above. Where do I add this in my screenOptions? Thank you.

Comment: Hi just now i noticed in my code, i think you need to add **<Stack.Navigator
      headerMode="none">** like this you don't need to change in <Tab.Navigator>. i just place the Tab.Navigator Inside Stack.Navigator for authentication purpose

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to work. It behaves similar to screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}. The back button is not showing.

Comment: Doing this options={{headerMode:"none"}} in stack navigator gives me the above, which I don't want.

Comment: So to clarify, you do not want to have the native header, but you want to have a custom header with a small black arrow and no title? I think that would require a custom header, not the removal of the header.

Comment: Additionally it might be good if you could add an Expo snack in your question, since there is a lot left over to the imagination. I already set something up here for you, you will need to create an account to save and share your Expo snack.

[LINK](https://snack.expo.dev/@fluous/react-navigation)

Comment: Hi, I'm not too bothered about what the colour of the arrow is. It can still be the default arrow. But as you can see from the last image above another header with the arrow and title has been added beneath. It looks like there are two headers which I don't want. In my app function I've already created a custom header: <Stack.Screen name="SearchListScreen" component={SearchListScreen} options={{title:null, headerTintColor:'black', headerBackTitle:' '}}/>.  And ok I'll check Expo

Answer (score 5):

The back button is part of the header, so you can't hide the header and keep the back button.

What you want to do is to hide other parts of the header except for the back button, which would be

- Title, with `headerTitle: ""`
- Background, with `headerTransparent: true`

Comment: Thanks. Where should I add this? Adding it in the Stack.Navigator like this <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerTitle:"", headerTransparent:true }}> causes the above image.

Comment: Is there a stack header and a screen header? Because looking at the images, it looks like there 2 headers. 1 for the stack (possibly) and another for the screen.

Comment: @AJDee well that's expected, the header is still there, but it's transparent, so your content goes below it. you need to add a top padding to your content so there's no overlap. you can use useHeaderHeight and add a padding https://reactnavigation.org/docs/elements#useheaderheight

Answer (score 1):

for hide the back button in react-native, we can use property,

> headerBackVisible:false this property only work on android

```js
<Stack.Screen
   options={{headerBackVisible: false}}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

example use of in Stack

```
const CustomerStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="First"
        component={First}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Third"
        component={Third}
        options={{headerTitle: '', headerTransparent: true}}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the default header then use like this

`screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}`

and write custom code for the header with back button in your component
(If your are using class component) Then

`<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.goBack()} style={{width:'100%', height:45, flexDirection:'row'}}> <Image source={require('back button image path')}/> </TouchableOpacity>`

if you want header title too then,

`<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.goBack()} style={{width:'100%', height:45, flexDirection:'row'}}> <Image source={require('back button image path')}/> <Text>SearchListScren</Text> </TouchableOpacity>`

Put this code at top of the component code under a container